Why is (n+1) the normalisation of a Binomial distribution’s likelihood function?
Say a random variable $X$ follows a binomial distribution $X\sim\text{Bin}(n,p)$ where $n$ is the number of trials, $p$ is the probability of success and $k$ is the number of successes. The likelihood function for $p$ is
$\mathcal{L}(p|X) = \binom{n}{k} p^k (1 - p)^{n - k}
$
The probability density function (PDF) for the distribution of $p$ can be arrived at using Bayesian inference but analytically it is known to be that of a Beta distribution. Assuming a uniform prior $p\sim\text{Beta}(k+1 , n-k+1)$ so its PDF is:
$
\begin{aligned}
f(p) & = \frac{p^k (1 - p)^{n - k}}{B(k+1, n-k+1)} \\
& = \frac{p^k (1 - p)^{n - k}}{\int_{0}^{1} t^k (1 - t)^{n - k} \, dt} \\
& = \frac{(n+1)!}{k!(n-k)!} p^k (1 - p)^{n - k} \\
& = (n+1) \binom{n}{k} p^k (1 - p)^{n - k} \\
& = (n+1) \mathcal{L}(p|X)
\end{aligned}
$
(using the definition of a Beta function for positive integers to convert from the integral in line 2 to the factorials in line 3).
This is fascinating to me. If we want to normalise the likelihood function so that the area under the curve is equal to $1$ and it makes a valid PDF, the normalisation is just $(n+1)$. Why is this? I can see it mathematically but what is the intuition behind it being this value and not something else?
